# Mysql for NodeJS not expanding array in queries

Tags: mysql, node.js

I'm using NodeJS and the [mysql](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql) package from npm. I'm having trouble selecting specific rows from the database by ID. I'm using a simple WHERE id IN (...) query, and passing in the ids as an array of numbers.

According to the documentation,

> Arrays are turned into list, e.g. ['a', 'b'] turns into 'a', 'b'

So I've written this code to debug the SQL it generates:

```
  console.log(ids);
  console.log(this.connection.format(
    "SELECT `invitations`.* FROM `invitations` WHERE `invitations`.`id` IN (?)",
    ids
  ));
```

I expect to see a list of ids first, then the SQL statement where those ids are in the IN section of the query.

However, only the first id is present in the query:

```
console.log tests/fakers/InvitationFaker.ts:70
[ 207, 208 ]

console.log tests/fakers/InvitationFaker.ts:71
SELECT `invitations`.* FROM `invitations` WHERE `invitations`.`id` IN (207)
```

Why doesn't the query look like this:

```
... WHERE `invitations`.`id` IN (207, 208)
```

?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm an idiot :) I forgot that the second argument can be either a single value or an array, but when it's an array, the first value fills the first `?` and so on. To expand an array, I need to do this:

```
" ... WHERE `id` IN ?", [ids]
```

(note the double array, since `ids` is already an array). For example:

```
" ... WHERE `id` IN ?", [[1, 2, 3, 4]]
```

Answer (score 0):

try to convert the ids to string with "," between the ids

```js
this.connection.format(
    "SELECT `invitations`.* FROM `invitations` WHERE `invitations`.`id` IN (?)",
    ids.join(",")
  ));
```